# How do I get a drag free drift when fly Fishing

Tags: fly-fishing, trout-fishing

We always hear about the importance of drag free drifts so I thought it would be great to create a resource listing techniques for achieving a drag free drift.

I've setup a community wiki for this as I already have some techniques for doing this it would be great if others could add to the wiki answer

Answer (score 1):

**Mending**

- Upstream mend
- Downstream mend
- Stack mend

---

**Presentation Casts**

- Reach cast
- Don't turn the leader over fully
- Tuck cast
- Puddle cast
- Snake cast
- Curve cast

---

**Gear**

- Thinner leader
- Longer leader
- [George Harvey leader formulation](https://troutbitten.com/2019/07/21/dry-fly-fishing-the-george-harvey-leader-design/) to introduce slack into the leader

Tight line nymphing can also be a great technique for reducing drag when casting across different current speeds

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what each of the mends and casts are? That would make this post much more useful.